# ASP.Net delete/expire session cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, cookies

We have a number of internal company ASP.Net applications.  All use Forms Authentication and all are session based...

What I am trying to do is when a user logs out of one application he/she is logged out of all applications.

I have some logic that iterates the cookies collection.  I can see all the other ASP.Net applications but I can not remove them.

Im currently using the following logic:

```
// expire all asp.net app tickets
        string[] allDomainCookes = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys;

        foreach (string domainCookie in allDomainCookes)
        {
            if (domainCookie.Contains("ASPXAUTH"))
            {
                var expiredCookie = new HttpCookie(domainCookie) { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1) };
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(expiredCookie);
            }
        }
        HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Clear();
```

For some reason they are not being removed.  I know they are all there because I have written them to the page.  They are just not being removed....is this because these are session cookies?

Also I should add they are all sub-domains of the some domain so ownership should not be an issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually...I've just found the problem.  I need to specify the domain as well

```
string[] allDomainCookes = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys;

    foreach (string domainCookie in allDomainCookes)
    {
        if (domainCookie.Contains("ASPXAUTH"))
        {
            var expiredCookie = new HttpCookie(domainCookie) { 
                  Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                  Domain = ".mydomain"
            };
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(expiredCookie);
        }
    }
    HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.Clear();
```

Answer (score 5):

try this code ..works for me

```
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
            HttpCookie cookie1 = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "");
            cookie1.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie1);
            HttpCookie cookie2 = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", "");
            cookie2.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie2);
```

Comment: He is implementing apparently his own Authentication system, this `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` should not be there.

Comment: Session.Clear();
Session.Abandon();
Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Cookies only works in the same domain. If it's cross domain, you need another solution. [Here is another article about Asp.net cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509141/get-session-to-expire-gracefully-in-asp-net)

Comment: Hi these are not cross domain.  These are subdomain i.e website1.contonso.com and website2.contonso.com etc

Comment: Even if cross domain, CORS can overcome this limitation of destroying cookies.